# Suggested edits broken?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11535346/18771) the OP (25 rep) made an edit to my answer.

It showed up instantly. This can't be right, can it?

However, there was a notification in my inbox that told me an edit was suggested. The history also speaks of "suggested edits". Yet it seems there's actually nothing for me to approve.

(SO rev 2012.7.17.3401)

Comment: Seems OK to me - the edit was approved by two users - http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/320719

Comment: @ChrisF Yes, it's all-right. A short hint in [the history *overview*](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11535531/revisions) à la "Approved by Sergey K., Jonathan" would have been nice. I did not inspect the individual history entries, so I was confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The edit was indeed suggested, but it was then approved by two others. See the [suggested edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/320719). There was a 9 minute gap between the suggestion and the second approval vote, so it was not instant.

If you found the suggested edit message before anyone had approved it, your vote would have been enough to clear or reject the suggestion; the original poster can veto edits while still in the queue (this only applies to Stack Overflow).

In other words, the suggested editing system was working as designed, making this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Also see [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

Comment: Ah, never mind. I did not expect such a quick reaction from the community.